# Display templates, managed properties showing null

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template, managed-property, crawled-property

In Sharepoint Online,trying to display one site collection list columns in another site collection using search and dispaly templates
List:/sites/UAT/Lists/SearchTestList/AllItems.aspx
[image]

1.Mapped the crawled properties with managed properties in both the site collections
[image]
 same mapping in /sites/UAT and /sites/Classic

2.Created a basic search center in /Sites/Classic and through query rules I am able to get the results

[image]

=>In Item_Default display template , I have added these Properties as 'RefinableString148':'RefinableString148','RefinableString149':'RefinableString149','RefinableString150':'RefinableString150'

=>In display templates, I am displaying as below

```
 <ul>
<li>    _#= ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString148 =#_ </li>
<li>    _#= ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString149 =#_ </li>
<li>    _#= ctx.CurrentItem.RefinableString150 =#_ </li>
<li>    _#= ctx.CurrentItem.Title =#_ </li>
<li>    _#= ctx.CurrentItem.LastModifiedTime =#_ </li>
</ul>
```

But the output is only displaying Title and LastModifiedTime of items
[image]

But the same properties are showing in Refiners
[image]

Am I missing anything or doing anything wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but have you tried adding the RefinableStrings into the ManagedPropertyMapping property? I found it on line 12 of my particular Display Template.

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;......&#39;RefinableString79&#39;:&#39;RefinableString79&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

Comment: Please update code part of your answer - it seems to have a broken closing tag.